# Problema con camara en flutter_Bloc

Tags: flutter

estoy presentado un problema en mi proyecto de flutter al implementar flutter_bloc ya que al momento de inicializar la app o al hacer un hot restart la camara no se muestra y he incluso los widgets que se encuentran dentro del BlocBuilder<CameraBloc,CameraSate> no responden (tienen una animacion), pero al momento en que toco uno de estos ahi si se muestra la camara pero los botones de control no se animan, dejo el codijo de los archivos debajo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:snapeat/bloc/camera/camera_bloc.dart';
import 'package:snapeat/bloc/utils/position_model_selector/position_model_bloc.dart';

import 'package:snapeat/home/home.dart';
import 'package:snapeat/theme/theme.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      home: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<CameraBloc>(
            create: (context) => CameraBloc()..add(InitializeCamera()),
          ),
          BlocProvider<PositionModelBloc>(create: (context) => PositionModelBloc())
        ],
        child: const Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

camera_bloc:

```
 import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
part 'camera_state.dart';
part 'camera_event.dart';

class CameraBloc extends Bloc<CameraEvent, CameraState> {
  bool activeFlash = false;
  int setflash = 0;
  double zoomLevel = 1.0;
  late CameraController cameraController;
  CameraBloc() : super(CameraInitial()) {
    on<InitializeCamera>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        cameraController = await controller();
        cameraController.initialize();

        emit(CameraReady(cameraController));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(CameraError(e.toString()));
      }
    });

    on<ToggleFlash>((event, emit) async {
      if (setflash <= 2) {
        setflash++;
      } else {
        setflash = 0;
      }
      await cameraController.setFlashMode(flashMode());
      emit(CameraReady(cameraController));
    });
    on<ZoomEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        zoomLevel = event.zoomLevel;
        await cameraController.setZoomLevel(event.zoomLevel);
        emit(CameraReady(cameraController));
        
      },
    );
    on<TakeAPicture>(
      (event, emit) {
        cameraController.takePicture();
        emit(CameraReady(cameraController));
      },
    );
  }
  controller() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();

    final control = CameraController(
      cameras.first,
      ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
      enableAudio: false,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );
    return control;
  }

  flashMode() {
    switch (setflash) {
      case 1:
        return FlashMode.auto;
      case 2:
        return FlashMode.always;
      case 3:
        return FlashMode.torch;
      default:
        return FlashMode.off;
    }
  }
}
```

camera_event:

```
 part of 'camera_bloc.dart';

abstract class CameraEvent extends Equatable {
  const CameraEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class InitializeCamera extends CameraEvent {}

class ToggleFlash extends CameraEvent {}

class ZoomEvent extends CameraEvent {
  final double zoomLevel;
  const ZoomEvent(this.zoomLevel);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [zoomLevel];
}

class TakeAPicture extends CameraEvent {}
```

camera_state:

```
 part of 'camera_bloc.dart';

abstract class CameraState extends Equatable {
  const CameraState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  get cameraController => null;
}


class CameraReady extends CameraState {
  @override
  final CameraController cameraController;

  const CameraReady(this.cameraController,);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [cameraController,];
}

class CameraError extends CameraState {
  final String errorMessage;

  const CameraError(this.errorMessage);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [errorMessage];
}
class CameraInitial extends CameraState {}
```

codigo del widget de la camara:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:snapeat/bloc/camera/camera_bloc.dart';

class Camera extends StatelessWidget {
  const Camera({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CameraWidget();
  }
}

class CameraWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CameraWidget> createState() => _CameraWidgetState();
}

class _CameraWidgetState extends State<CameraWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
          switchInCurve: Curves.easeIn,
          switchOutCurve: Curves.easeOut,
          child: _buildCameraStateWidget(state),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildCameraStateWidget(CameraState state) {
  try {
    if (state is CameraReady) {
      return CameraPreviewWidget(cameraController: state.cameraController);
    } else if (state is CameraError) {
      return CameraErrorWidget(state.errorMessage);
    } else {
      return const LoadingWidget();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return Text(e.toString());
  }
}

class CameraPreviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraController cameraController;

  const CameraPreviewWidget({super.key, required this.cameraController});

  @override
  State<CameraPreviewWidget> createState() => _CameraPreviewWidgetState();
}

class _CameraPreviewWidgetState extends State<CameraPreviewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CameraPreview(widget.cameraController);
  }
}

class CameraErrorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String errorMessage;

  const CameraErrorWidget(this.errorMessage, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(errorMessage);
    return Center(
      child: Text("Error: $errorMessage"),
    );
  }
}

class LoadingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya pude solucionar el problema, al aprecer faltaba un await del cameracontroller en el InitializeCamera, y por eso se disparaba el evento aun estando null

```
on<InitializeCamera>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        cameraController = await controller();
        await cameraController?.initialize(); // Esperar a que se inicialice el CameraController
        emit(
          CameraReady(cameraController!, zoomLevel, setflash, imagePath, compressedPath),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        emit(CameraError(e.toString()));
      }
    });
```

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes (además, ¿cómo uno haría _copypaste_ de una imagen?) Lee [answer], pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta, y no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).